# Is it valid to compare iterators which are got from the container separately?

Tags: c++, stl

For example, it this expression valid in semantic?

```
container.begin() == container.begin();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, so long as neither iterator has been invalidated.

For example, the following would not be valid:

```
std::deque<int> d;

std::deque<int> begin1 = d.begin();
d.push_front(42);                   // invalidates begin1!
std::deque<int> begin2 = d.begin();
assert(begin1 == begin2);           // wrong; you can't use begin1 anymore.
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `begin()` will return the same iterator given a container instance, unless you change the container in some way (`end()` has this property as well). For example, `std::vector::push_back()` may cause the array to be reallocated to accommodate new elements.

Comment: Be carefull using the term `same`. I don't think all containers will return the `same` iterator for the same item. Though they will compare equal when compared with ==.

Comment: Martin York's comment still holds: Each call to `begin()` will return a different iterator even if they compare the same. This is being picky at this time, but the iterators will not be the same. `&c.begin() != &c.begin()` even if `c.begin() == c.begin()` (assuming single threaded context).